# Select all records from master table, but conditionally only one from detail table

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to select all records from master table GROUPS, but only the appropriate one from detail table SESSIONS?

Older postings have led me to believe a LEFT JOIN subquery is needed for this.
The query below seems to work, but only for the first record.
Subsequent records return NULL values for session_start etc.

How to get session data for all group records?

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.group_name
  FROM groups g

LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT session_id,
          group_id,
          session_start,
          session_stop
     FROM sessions
    WHERE :current_time < session_stop
 ORDER BY :current_time BETWEEN session_start AND session_stop DESC,
          session_stop
    LIMIT 1 ) s
ON s.group_id = g.group_id
```

The rules for conditionally returning the single record from "sessions" are:

1. Return the session record where current_time is between session_ start and session_stop.
2. Else, if none such exists, return the first session record where current_time is less than session_start.
3. Sessions having current_time larger than session_stop must not be returned.

The two tables, "groups"and "sessions":

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
    group_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    group_name VARCHAR UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE
);

CREATE TABLE sessions (
    session_id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    group_id        INTEGER REFERENCES groups (group_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    session_start   REAL,
    session_stop    REAL
);
```

groups table content:

```
group_id    group_name
1           Group 1
2           Group 2
```

sessions table content:

```
session_id  group_id    session_start   session_stop
1       1               2459603.875     2459604.2291666665
2       1               2459604.875     2459605.2291666665
3       1               2459605.875     2459606.2291666665
261     2               2459603.875     2459604.2291666665
262     2               2459604.875     2459605.2291666665
263     2               2459605.875     2459606.2291666665
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to pick 1 row from `sessions` for each `group_id`:

```
SELECT g.*, s.*
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY group_id
              ORDER BY julianday('now','localtime') BETWEEN session_start AND session_stop DESC,
                       session_start 
            ) rn
  FROM sessions
  WHERE julianday('now','localtime') <= session_stop
) s ON s.group_id = g.group_id AND s.rn = 1;
```

Comment: That was fast, and seems to work too! Have to do a few tests first though. Would you by any chance know how to replace the :current_time in the LEFT JOIN with this instead: julianday('Now','localtime') AS julian_now. I get the "column not exist" message.

Comment: @Rimfire I used `:current_time` in my code because I saw it in your code and it seemed that you want to pass it as a parameter. The correct thing to do is to use `julianday('Now','localtime')`, but you can't give it an alias. See my edited code.

Comment: Parameter or julianday() are both fine. Thanks for confirming that the alias can't be used in that part of the code.